# textView inside scrollview but it's not on top of keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have a chat app with a textView inside of a dock UIImageView as usual but they aren't sitting on top of the keyboard and when the keyboard is down it doesn't drop down to the bottom of the screen either. The spacing varies between devices too as you can see in the screen shots. I included a link to an imgur album rather than embedding so many images. Also in my app the keyboard never goes down. I did this on purpose. It only comes up when the app is opened. But since there are so many devices how do you make the scrollView sit on top of the keyboard?  Btw, when we do this in chat apps with messages in a table is it the scrollView we want sitting on top of the keyboard or is it the tableView that should do it?

http://imgur.com/a/vyTBu

Answer (score 0):

Make sure TextField at the bottom of view controller. Set constraint Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide.

[image]

Comment: Hi. I'm using textView. Even still, there is no Bottom Layout Guide option. My textView is nested inside a docView then tableView.